# How can i click the input type="button" with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events, click

Is there any ways to click the input `"type=button"`?

I used the Selector from input line and received the following error:

> VM6073:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '# d185940-3e8b-4d2d-6f08-077bb502c07f' is not a valid selector.**

My code is:

```js
const clickArea = document.querySelector('#\38 c3162aa-22f4-46d1-cf1c-29af7ad30dda')

const clickEvent = clickArea.querySelector('input').click()
```

```html
<div id="8c3162aa-22f4-46d1-cf1c-29af7ad30dda" style="width:900px;height:40px;"><input type="button" id="3e6eda1c-fbb7-4202-ed3f-6090d0a3e465" value="다운로드" style="width:92px;height:30px;float:right;margin-right:10px;margin-top:5px; font-family:Malgun Gothic;font-size:12px;background:#FFFFFF;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#4072CB;" class=""></div>

    <input type="button" id="3e6eda1c-fbb7-4202-ed3f-6090d0a3e465" value="다운로드" style="width:92px;height:30px;float:right;margin-right:10px;margin-top:5px; font-family:Malgun Gothic;font-size:12px;background:#FFFFFF;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#4072CB;" class="">
```

It doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's not a valid selector. Remove the space between '#' and 'c3162aa-22f4-46d1-cf1c-29af7ad30dda'. You are also selecting the div and not the button.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong element.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

function showMessage() {
  alert('hello');
}

btn.addEventListener('click', showMessage);

btn.click()
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query selector was formed wrong, and it worked when I changed it to getElementById.  Not sure if this is entirely what you're looking for but it's the best I've got based on your question.

```
const clickArea = document.getElementById('3e6eda1c-fbb7-4202-ed3f-6090d0a3e465');

clickArea.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change like this

```js
const clickArea = document.querySelector('div[id="8c3162aa-22f4-46d1-cf1c-29af7ad30dda"]')

const clickEvent = clickArea.querySelector('input').click()
```

```html
<div id="8c3162aa-22f4-46d1-cf1c-29af7ad30dda" style="width:900px;height:40px;"><input type="button" id="3e6eda1c-fbb7-4202-ed3f-6090d0a3e465" value="다운로드" style="width:92px;height:30px;float:right;margin-right:10px;margin-top:5px; font-family:Malgun Gothic;font-size:12px;background:#FFFFFF;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#4072CB;" class=""></div>

<input type="button" id="3e6eda1c-fbb7-4202-ed3f-6090d0a3e465" value="다운로드" style="width:92px;height:30px;float:right;margin-right:10px;margin-top:5px; font-family:Malgun Gothic;font-size:12px;background:#FFFFFF;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#4072CB;" class="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use double backslashes to escape the leading number:

```js
const clickArea = document.querySelector('#\\38 c3162aa-22f4-46d1-cf1c-29af7ad30dda')
 
clickArea.querySelector('input').click()
```

```html
<div id="8c3162aa-22f4-46d1-cf1c-29af7ad30dda" style="width:900px;height:40px;"><input type="button" id="3e6eda1c-fbb7-4202-ed3f-6090d0a3e465" value="다운로드" style="width:92px;height:30px;float:right;margin-right:10px;margin-top:5px; font-family:Malgun Gothic;font-size:12px;background:#FFFFFF;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#4072CB;" class=""></div>

<input type="button" id="3e6eda1c-fbb7-4202-ed3f-6090d0a3e465" value="다운로드" style="width:92px;height:30px;float:right;margin-right:10px;margin-top:5px; font-family:Malgun Gothic;font-size:12px;background:#FFFFFF;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#4072CB;" class="">
```